# Dividir sub-lista em python

Tags: python, lista

Bom time, tenho um método que recebe uma lista e a partir dela cria sub-lista e anexa nos buckets:

```
def indexar(self, keys):
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    for i in keys:
        for ii in range(10):
            if i % 10 == ii:
                buckets[ii].append(i)
```

Quando passo a lista:

```
keys = list(range(0, 100)
```

Retorno:

```
Buckets[0] = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

A partir disso queria dividir todas as sub-lista Buckets[] para tamanho 3, exemplo:

```
nova[0] = [[0, 10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90]]
```

Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
   novo = list()
    for i in range(0, len(buckets)):
        for ii in range(0, len(buckets[i]), 3):
            novo.append(list(buckets[i][ii:ii + 3]))
    return novo
```

Só que assim ela apenas fatia as sub-lista, mas não encadeia.
Código completo:

```
def indexar(self, keys):
    buckets = []
    for _ in range(10):
        buckets.append([])

    for i in keys:
        for ii in range(10):
            if i % 10 == ii:
                buckets[ii].append(i)

    nova = []

    for i in range(0, len(buckets)):
        for ii in range(0, len(buckets[i]), 3):
            nova.append(list(buckets[i][ii:ii + 3]))
    return nova
```

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo de uma lista de entrada e uma lista de saída que deseja obter?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, pode dar uma olhada se ficou mais claro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a entrada e a saída:

```
def indexar(values):
    # Contador iniciado em 0
    count = 0
    # Lista com até 10 listas
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho da lista buckets
    for r in range(0, len(buckets)):
        # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho da lista values
        for s in range(0, len(values)):
            # Verifica se r é multiplo de 3
            if s % 3 == 0:
                # Faz uma list comprehension pra armazenar em buckets no índice r
                # os valores dentro do range atual começando pelo 
                # índice s e finalizando no índice s + 3
                # e somando cada valor de values com o contador
                buckets[r].append([v + count for v in values[s:s + 3]])
        # Incrementa ao contador + 1
        count += 1
    # Retorna lista
    return buckets

foo = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print(indexar(foo))

# Saída: [[[0, 10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90]], [[1, 11, 21], [31, 41, 51], [61, 71, 81], [91]], [[2, 12, 22], [32, 42, 52], [62, 72, 82], [92]], [[3, 13, 23], [33, 43, 53], [63, 73, 83], [93]], [[4, 14, 24], [34, 44, 54], [64, 74, 84], [94]], [[5, 15, 25], [35, 45, 55], [65, 75, 85], [95]], [[6, 16, 26], [36, 46, 56], [66, 76, 86], [96]], [[7, 17, 27], [37, 47, 57], [67, 77, 87], [97]], [[8, 18, 28], [38, 48, 58], [68, 78, 88], [98]], [[9, 19, 29], [39, 49, 59], [69, 79, 89], [99]]]
```

Comment: Victor, nesse caso só ocorre a divisão de uma sub-lista, eu queria dividir todas elas e encadear o resultado. A saída deveria ser assim, Saída: [[[0, 10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90]], [[1, 11, 21], [ 31, 41, 51], [61, 71, 81], [91]], ...]

Comment: Pq def indexar deve rodar em buckets que é uma lista com 10 sub-listas

Comment: Neste caso editei a resposta @jusintique,

Comment: Victor, perfeito! Muito obrigada! Mas uma dúvida que surgiu aplicando essa função seria possível realizar essa divisão com dict através das keys dos elementos? Sem querer abusar ...

Comment: Bom, essa seria outra pergunta, então por gentileza faça uma nova pergunta aqui no StackOverflow detalhando as possíveis entradas e as saídas desejadas e se quiser compartilhe aqui o link. Estou à Disposição!

Comment: Victor, antes de postar a a nova pergunta, fiquei na seguinte dúvida, como utilizar sua função se foo = list(range(100))

Comment: Desculpa pela demora para entender pq a função não estava retornando a sua Saída.

Comment: Não entendi. Você gostaria de passar um valor qualquer não sendo apenas 10 mas 100 também? Se for isso, você pode criar um parâmetro na função indexar e mudar o valor 10 pelo nome do parâmetro.

Comment: A questão é só como obter o mesmo resultado, mas passando outro parâmetro. No seu exemplo, o parâmetro passado foi foo = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90], eu queria passar foo = list(range(100)), e obter exatamente o mesmo resultado

Comment: Certo, para isso você pode utilizar o step da função range:

foo = list(range(0, 100, 10))

Assim é possível gerar uma lista maior de 10 em 10.

Comment: Sim amigo. Ele irá incrementar de 10 em 10. Ou seja, a lista que você irá atribuir em foo será [0, 10, 20, 30... até 466550].

Comment: Foi sim, muito obrigada mesmo! Ate apaguei o comentário, pq tinha percebido. Acabei de postar a outra questão, pode dar uma olhada? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/448631/dividir-dicion%c3%a1rio-em-python

Comment: Que isso, sem problemas! Vamos lá.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vamos ver como fazer com uma única lista:

```
def split(lista, tamanho):
    return [lista[i:i + tamanho] for i in range(0, len(lista), tamanho)]

lista = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print(split(lista, 3)) # [[0, 10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90]]
```

A ideia para dividir em listas de tamanho N é pegar de N em N (repare no terceiro parâmetro do [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), ele diz que devemos pular de `tamanho` em `tamanho`, em vez de pular de 1 em 1), e ir pegando uma sub-lista contendo N elementos (`lista[i:i + tamanho]`).

Tendo esta função, basta aplicá-la para cada elemento do seu *bucket*:

```
nova_lista = [ split(b, 3) for b in buckets ]
```

Claro, se quiser também pode fazer com um *loop*:

```
nova_lista = []
for b in buckets:
    nova_lista.append(split(b, 3))
```

---

## Python 3.12

E a partir do [**Python 3.12**](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) (outubro de 2023) é possível usar a [função `itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), que serve justamente para retornar pedaços de um iterável, um por vez. Então a função `split` poderia ser assim:

```py
from itertools import batched

def split(lista, tamanho):
    return [ list(chunk) for chunk in batched(lista, tamanho) ]
```