# Dividir dicionário em python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Bom galera, até por ajuda aqui do fórum, consegui uma função que cria sub-lista a partir de sub-listas de acordo com a divisão por 10, fica mais fácil de entender com o código:

```
def indexar(values):
    # Contador iniciado em 0
    count = 0
    # Lista com até 10 listas
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho da lista buckets
    for r in range(0, len(buckets)):
        # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho da lista values
        for s in range(0, len(values)):
            # Verifica se r é multiplo de 3
            if s % 3 == 0:
                # Faz uma list comprehension pra armazenar em buckets no índice r
                # os valores dentro do range atual começando pelo 
                # índice s e finalizando no índice s + 3
                # e somando cada valor de values com o contador
                buckets[r].append([v + count for v in values[s:s + 3]])
        # Incrementa ao contador + 1
        count += 1
    # Retorna lista
    return buckets

foo = [0, 100, 10]
print(indexar(foo))

# Saída: [[[0, 10, 20], [30, 40, 50], [60, 70, 80], [90]], [[1, 11, 21], [31, 41, 51], [61, 71, 81], [91]], [[2, 12, 22], [32, 42, 52], [62, 72, 82], [92]], [[3, 13, 23], [33, 43, 53], [63, 73, 83], [93]], [[4, 14, 24], [34, 44, 54], [64, 74, 84], [94]], [[5, 15, 25], [35, 45, 55], [65, 75, 85], [95]], [[6, 16, 26], [36, 46, 56], [66, 76, 86], [96]], [[7, 17, 27], [37, 47, 57], [67, 77, 87], [97]], [[8, 18, 28], [38, 48, 58], [68, 78, 88], [98]], [[9, 19, 29], [39, 49, 59], [69, 79, 89], [99]]]
```

Mas a curiosidade bateu, e fiquei na dúvida se da para obter o mesmo resultado da função acima, não em uma lista simples, mas sim em uma lista de dict's, utilizando as keys dos elementos como parâmetros:

```
dict = {0: 123, 10: 456, 20: 789 ...}
onde as keys são os dois primeiros números dos elementos
```

A saída que quero obter seria:

```
[[[0: 123, 10: 456, 20: 789], ...]]]
```

Já consegui criar os dicionários, a partir do resto da divisão:

```
listOfDicts = [{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k%10==i} for i in range(10)]
```

Agora falta dividir as sublista ...

class Buckets:

```
def __init__(self, keys, palavras, tamanhoP):
    self.listaBuckts = dict()
    self.keys = list(keys)

    aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
    self.aux2 = list()

    for i in range(0, len(aux), tamanhoP):
        self.aux2.append(dict(aux[i:i + tamanhoP]))

def criarB(self):
    for i, pag in enumerate(self.aux2):
        for v in pag.keys():
            self.listaBuckts[v] = i
    return '\n DICT COM TODOS OS ELEMENTOS DOS BUCKETS CRIADOS!'

# É criada uma função que receberá alguns parâmetros, como o dicionário, o tamanho do bucket e o tamanho do sub-dicionário.
def index_dict(self, tam_subdict):
    # Contador iniciado em 0
    count = 0
    # Criar de 0 até tam_bucket de listas dentro do bucket
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(10)]

    # O índice r vai de 0 até tam_bucket
    for r in range(0, len(buckets)):
        # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho das keys do dicionário com o step igual a tam_subdict
        for s in range(0, len(list(self.listaBuckts.keys())), tam_subdict):
            # Faz uma dict comprehension pra armazenar em no índice r do bucket
            # e somando cada valor de k com o contador count
            buckets[r].append(
                {k + count: v for k, v in self.listaBuckts.items()}
            )
        # Incrementa ao contador + 1
        count += 1
    # Retorna lista com os dicionários
    return buckets[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá:

> obter o mesmo resultado da função acima, não em uma lista simples, mas sim em uma lista de dict's, utilizando as keys dos elementos como parâmetros.
>
> Com seguinte saída: [[{0: 123, 10: 456, 20: 789}, ...]]]

```
# É criada uma função que receberá alguns parâmetros, como o dicionário, o tamanho do bucket e o tamanho do sub-dicionário.
def index_dict(dicionario, tam_bucket, tam_subdict):
    # Contador iniciado em 0
    count = 0
    # Criar de 0 até tam_bucket de listas dentro do bucket
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(tam_bucket)]

    # O índice r vai de 0 até tam_bucket
    for r in range(0, len(buckets)):
        # O índice vai de 0 até o tamanho das keys do dicionário com o step igual a tam_subdict
        for s in range(0, len(list(dicionario.keys())), tam_subdict):
            # Faz uma dict comprehension pra armazenar em no índice r do bucket
            # e somando cada valor de k com o contador count
            buckets[r].append(
                {k + count: v for k,v in dicionario.items()}
            )
        # Incrementa ao contador + 1
        count += 1
    # Retorna lista com os dicionários
    return buckets

# É criado um dicionário. (Só funciona com número como chave, pois se passar string acarreta em erro na função).
my_dict = {0: 123, 10: 456, 20: 789}
# Atribui o tamanho do bucket na varável tam_bucket.
tam_bucket = 10
# Atribui o tamanho dos sub-dicionarios na variável tam_dict
tam_subdict = 3

print(index_dict(my_dict, tam_bucket, tam_subdict))

# Saída: [[{0: 123, 10: 456, 20: 789}], [{1: 123, 11: 456, 21: 789}], [{2: 123, 12: 456, 22: 789}], [{3: 123, 13: 456, 23: 789}], [{4: 123, 14: 456, 24: 789}], [{5: 123, 15: 456, 25: 789}], [{6: 123, 16: 456, 26: 789}], [{7: 123, 17: 456, 27: 789}], [{8: 123, 18: 456, 28: 789}], [{9: 123, 19: 456, 29: 789}]]
```

Comment: Victor, tentei aplicar a sua função na minha classe, mas acredita que com um dicionário bem maior, ela acarreta em um erro de memória? tem como me ajudar? postei a class completa ...

Comment: Qual é o erro de saída?

Comment: Ele trava o pc por falta de memoria,

Comment: Talvez seja pelo tamanho do dicionário ?

Comment: Isso pode estar acontecendo pelo tamanho do dicionário que você está passando pra função, Recomendo você tentar particionar esse dicionário em um arquivo separado e chamar ele para você ter a saída esperada aos poucos, para não ter um stackoverflow de memória.

Comment: Tem com me dar um exemplo de como fazer ? Estou imaginando mil coisas haha

Comment: Eu acredito hehehe, Bom, sua fonte de dados pode ser um arquivo txt, ou um json, ou até mesmo um banco de dados (mais recomendado por fazer melhor a gestão da memória). Peço, para criar outra pergunta aqui no StackOverflow ou então pode dar uma conferida nesse link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Ele irá te ajudar em como carregar grandes arquivos com pouco espaço em disco ou ram.